# My class moves up when I type something in it

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<!--start of steps-->  
    <div id="stepscontainer">
    <div class="step">
    <p>STEP 1</p>
    <p style="font-size:12px;">SHARE US WITH YOUR FRIENDS</p>
    </div>

    <div class="step">
    <p>STEP 2</p>
    <p style="font-size:12px;">COMPLETE A SHORT OFFER</p>
    </div>

    <div class="step">
    <p>STEP 3</p>
    <p style="font-size:12px;">ENJOY YOUR FREE RUNESCAPE MEMBERSHIP</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--end of steps-->
```

CSS

```
.step{
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#121001;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    }
.step p{
    font-size:30px;

    }   
#stepscontainer{
    height:200px;
    width:900px;
    position:relative;
    top:-610px;
    text-align:center;
    }
```

In step the it is moved up a little bit because there is two blocks of line, is there any way to keep them aligned even when there is more than one line of text?

Answer (score 1):

"*Is there any way to keep them aligned even when there is more than one line of text?*"

Adding `vertical-align: bottom;` to the `.step` class is one way:

```
.step{
width:250px;
height:200px;
background-color:#FFF;
color:#121001;
display:inline-block;
padding-right:20px;
margin-right:10px;
margin-left:10px;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jTD8q/

Comment: my night in shining armour

Answer (score 0):

```
.step{
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

So that all of them are aligned on top despite their content.

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cfSf7/)